# ListView on Android HomeScreen Widget

Tags: android, android-listview, widget, android-widget, android-appwidget

So I have a text view in my Homescreen widget, but unfortunately the text data is too big and apparently text view can not be made scrollable in an app widget.

So I want to create a listview and just have the text view data at it's 1st position.

I have searched a lot on the internet and here at stackOverflow but haven't been able to make the listview working on my app widget.

Can someone please add a simple code for this. 
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try webview ?

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi Unfortunately Android app widgets (homescreen widget) don't support webviews.